# question on gradual data import on pelias service

Tags: pelias

I successfully provisioned a pelias service thanks to the [pelias-docker](https://github.com/pelias/docker) tool, using one of the data importer projects it offers.

Now i need to feed more data to that pelias service instance and unsure of how to proper do that.

- enter other data project and point to the same service instance?
- use importer projects like [csv-iporter](https://github.com/pelias/csv-importer) directly?

tried already the first one but ended up in error, not sure if the shared data folder is the cause or i just got a faulty data project.

any guidance is welcome.